# How can an algorithm interpret a directed node graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

## Problem: interpreting a node graph

Recently I have been interested in node editors, and by that I'm referring to editors such as the ones seen and used in [Maya](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-23277302-6665-465F-8579-9BC734228F69-htm.html), [Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/index.html), [Substance Painter](https://support.allegorithmic.com/documentation/display/SD5/Nodes+Reference), and also in [Unreal Engine 4](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/).

My code is separated in two parts, one side handles the UI (creating nodes, moving nodes, attaching nodes) And the other one, the one I'm working on right now is the interpreter which basically reads the graph.

Here's a screenshot of showing three nodes connected by edges (they are directed always go this way: pink -> green). One node can have multiple parameters (green docks) and multiple return values (green docks).

[image]

Just to be clear, I have an object that updates when things change onscreen (node connection, node creation/deletion). I want to create an algorithm that interprets/read the graph in order to run the program described by the nodes.

I found [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/6e45y2/how_would_you_implement_a_node_editor_in_your/) which helped me a bit in understanding the problem. However I'm still not confident enough to start writing the code for it.

I'm assuming there needs to be a starting node, something to initiate the reading of the graph but then the problem I face is when it gets more complicated, such as a graph with multiple input nodes.

(Bellow image has annotation in red.)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I'll need this object to read the graph."? Why not keeping track of editing actions directly in the model?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that. The object I am referring to in my post is actually the one you're mentioning here. It keeps track of edits/changes in the node and contains all connection between nodes.

Answer (score 3):

## Directed node path:

### The following algorithm will interpret this graph node:

[image]

Some more details on the node graph:

1. Green docks are variables that come from other nodes, so they are
   necessarily objects outputted by a previous node. On the other hand
   square docks are constants.
2. I will refer to "control object" the object that holds all links between docks in the graph.

---

**-- START OF ALGORITHM --**

- search all input nodes, meaning all nodes that have no links attached on their left (no parameter).

  > there are five on this graph: A, B, C, E, and K they have only constant docks on their left: A1, B1, B2, C1, E1, E2, K1, and K2 are all
  >   defined variables.
- nodes are functions, and input nodes are functions without parameters. No other values are needed, therefore we can calculate
  the output of those five nodes.

  > these outputs are A2, B3, C2, E3, E4, K3.
- with our control object we know which docks are connected to these four outputs

  > they link like so: A2 -> D1; B3 -> D2; C2 -> D3; C2 -> F1; E3 -> G2; E4 -> J1; K3 -> N3

NOTE: pink docks who link up to multiple green docks are processed as if there were multiple identical pink docks. Here, for example, the output C2 of the node C can be seen as C2 and C2' (because C2 links up to D3 AND to F1). In total, we have 7 links to analyze.

- yet again with our control object, we will look at where those 7 links end up.

  > they end in the D, F, G, J and N nodes
- they end up on five different nodes. Now, can we calculate the D output, the F output, the G output, the J output and the N output? Or
  do we need other variables that we don't have right now?

  > node D has three parameters and it just happens that we have all three parameters: D1, D2, D3 so we can calculate D's output right
  >   now: D4
  >   node F has only one parameter and we have F1, we can calculate F's output: F2
  >   node G has two parameters but we only have G2, we can't calculate G's output => store G2 in G's waiting queue in the control object
  >   node J same thing we have J1 but not J2 => store J1 in J's waiting queue in the control object
  >   node N has three parameters but we only have N3
- at the end of this step we have calculated D4 and F2 and stored in our control object the following values: N3 (which hasn't been used
  because we don't yet have N1, N2), G2 (because we don't have G1) and
  J1 (because we don't have J2). Now let's look at where D4 and F2 end
  up

  [image]

  > D4 ends up on the G node: on the G1 dock (therefore the object in D4 dock equals the object in G1)
  >   F2 ends up on J node: on the J2 dock (same here)
- can we calculate G and J?

  > for G we have 2 parameters on 2 so we can get G3
  >   for J we have 2 parameters on 2 so we can get J3

  [image]
- check where G3 and J3 end

  > H, I and L nodes
- can we calculate them?

  > H has two parameters: H2 equal to G3 and the other one is set => we calculate H3
  >   I has two parameters: I1 equal to G3 and the other one is set => we calculate I3
  >   L has only one parameter: L1 => we calculate L2
- where does H3, I3, L2 end up at?

  > M and N
- can we calculate M and N?

  > M has two parameters, we have M1 and M2 => we can calculate M3
  >   N has three parameters, we have N3 from the first step stored in N's parameters array and N2 is equal to L2 => we cannot calculate N
- we have one more vertex to sort out: M3

  > it goes to N, M3 = N1
- can we calculate N?

  > now we can because we have N1, N2, N3 => we can calculate node N (no output in this case)
- No more vertices to sort

**-- END OF ALGORITHM --**

Comment: Unrelated to the algorithm: I would change the "square docks" to "constant nodes". This will come in handy if there is a constant that needs to be shared between different nodes.

Comment: Now I don't know if there's a better way. But the above algorithm will only run the code described in the graph, it will not 'transcript' it into actual JS code, which I'm interested in doing. I guess it will get some more work to do

Comment: Unless you have a very specific reason why you want to evaluate the graph starting from input nodes, I'd suggest you do the opposite and resolve the dependencies from the desired output. This way, you do not risk computing nodes which might be not used downstream; moreover, you can easily figure out which node computations can be parallelized. If you're still interested, I might take some time and expand on this (I'm no expert but I've seen quite a few examples around and it'd be a good exercise for me too...)

Comment: @mapofemergence Cool, someone on Reddit said the same: starting with the 'end nodes'. While I made it work with the more direct approach I don't really know how to tackle this... Basically what I need to do is search of 'end nodes' and go up the tree to find it's parameters until there is no more nodes connected. Is that not less efficient? This algorithm would have to travel the graph backwards to find all necessary parameters and then forward to actually calculate the result... Also what's parallelized computation in an algorithm? Thanks for the feedback! I'll put the code in a github repo.

Comment: @Ivan you can trigger graph evaluation by selecting the nodes to resolve or via callbacks (ie. nodes have UI and those contain an `execute` button). Regarding efficiency, looping through nodes twice instead than once has a minimal footprint, unless you have an immense number of nodes, especially if you're able to skip irrelevant node computations (normally more expensive than pure iterations). By parallelizing I mean processing computation on different threads. Generally, it all depends from what your logic does and your coding language: sharing the code on github would definitely help to tell

Comment: @mapofemergence, all right I'm going to finish sort my files and then I push them to the repo. The current (direct) interpreter I have coded works and allows me to interpret all the necessary nodes (by that I mean: all nodes which aren't linked are left aside, only the linked ones are accessed). Each node UI is associated with an object which contains various elements,  in particular the function it needs to run. So when all parameters on a node are found the function is run immediately.

Comment: @mapofemergence Just another thing, in the long run I was thinking of doing an actual transcript of the code. So the interpreter would not only reads and runs the code but it actually write the code in programming language. Do you know if it's feasible with this kind of algorithm (direct or indirect)? (anyway that's not the main concern here, I need to focus on the indirect graph interpreter)

Comment: Here's the [repo for this project](https://github.com/WonJunior/CodeGraph). Only the `interpreter/interpreter.js` file has been documented so far.

Comment: Sorry I got back to this just now; the next days will be hectic too for me, so I might need some time for a proper answer :/ Also, I'm no JS expert, then what I'd suggest might need some adjustments, based on the language paradigms. Anyway, I'll post a first general idea in a separate comment (just to have some more text-space) and will try to produce a better, more articulated answer ASAP, after having dug your code a bit more

Comment: @Ivan If OOP is an option, I think it's the most flexible approach: each node is a specialized object containing the logic it needs and storing references to its input connections; when called, it queries its inputs for the required values before computing; recursively, each node will query its own inputs until every dependency is resolved (when a node computes a value, it stores it internally, to return it directly on next calls). Producing a trancript of your logic sounds doable but how easy vs hard it might be, will depend on the complexity of your graph's logic. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @mapofemergence Yes OOP is the idea, currently all UI nodes are instances of Node and all have their properties and methods. The current node interpreter works fine for basic/linear programs. I've looked more into your idea of an indirect interpreter and now it makes more sense. Here's why: the goal for this project is to be able to "graph" any algorithm/program, and for that I need `loops` and `if,else statements`...

Comment: @mapofemergence I have made a post on the new interpreter!

Answer (score 1):

## Interpreter version 2

The problem with the previous answer was that it only dealt with simple/linear programs. In other words, it couldn't deal with operations such as condition checks: `if, else` and most of all loops: `for` and `while`. Based on the discussion I had with [mapofemergence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8200213/mapofemergence) I've decided to work on this issue in order to create a more versatile interpreter that would compile pretty much any graph structure. So here's an update on the **Node Graph Interpreter**!

I have been looking around the Unreal Engine docs a bit and I find out some really cool things about how their node graph works. Basically, they have a different type of link between nodes called `execution links`. Furthermore, they have other types of nodes called `control nodes` that handle conditions and loops. So in this answer, I'm going to be looking at how to implement them and how the interpreter will function in order to run them.

Let's take two simple examples:

```
// CODE A
total = 0
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    total++;
}
print(total)
```

and

```
// CODE B
total = 0
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    total++;
    print(total);
}
```

The first displays `total` at the end, the second one displays it on each loop.

Now how do we implement it with nodes?

1. we need the body of the loop:

[image]

2. then we need a new node to control the loop, the `loop node`:

[image]

See that purple dock? This is the execution dock, it indicates order. That's cool because it tells the interpreter exactly what to do on each loop.

---

### Let's create `CODE A`:

[image]

---

### Let's do `CODE B`:

`CODE B` requires that we add a "callback" dock to the `loop node`:

[image]

Here's `CODE B`:

[image]

---

### Conclusion

Essentially the interpreter (version 2!) works as follows:

When the `loop node` is called (we'll have to add a purple dock on the left side of the `loop` node in order to call it) the interpreter will follow its existing control link (purple link) and linearly work its way, one node at the time.

In our example `CODE A`, the `loop node` is attached to `add` first it must resolve all its dependencies before moving onto the next node attached by the control link (here `print`). That corresponds to `BLOCK 1` (see the last image).

#### BLOCK 1

The node `add` has to pull variable `total` no further calculation needed to calculate his arguments, all arguments have been resolved (the other one is set to `1`). Therefore calculate the output of `add` and find the nodes attached to it: we have a node `total` attached on the right (it's a `set` function, the other one was a `get`). Move to this node and proceed: no nodes attached to this one => move to the second node linked by control link: BLOCK 2.

#### BLOCK 2

The node has one argument, it pulls the variable `total` and runs its function, therefore, printing the variable `total` (which has been incremented by 1 by the preceding node).

#### All in all

Here's the graph with the blocks I was mentioning previously
[image]

Two things to understand:

1 - there are two types of links: `data links`  and `control links`, the former was used in the first interpreter and the latter was introduced in this post.

2 - this interpreter will switch between

- *direct interpretation*:

  - when navigation through a control link (purple link) the interpretation will be direct (in `CODE A` the interpreter went like so: `loop node` -> `add node` -> `print node`)
  - <strike>whenever a node that is attached by a control link has its output attached to other node(s). (in `CODE A` the `add node` is attached on the right to a `total` node)</strike>
- *indirect interpretation*: when resolving dependencies on a node that is attached by a control link, the interpreter will have to work its way backward in order to find the node's arguments. (in `CODE A` the

---

### EDIT

Some modifications have to be made to this interpreter here's the problem:

> I'm not sure how you would update the input total for the add node after each iteration
>
> - [mapofemergence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8200213/mapofemergence)

Here's how we solve this: `ADD` shouldn't have an execution pin and the `SET` node should have one instead. Here's the correct graph to run `CODE A`:

[image]

Let's recap:

- *forward interpretation* for all nodes attached with control links
- *backward interpretation* to find the arguments of a node

Also, an actual variable object (we will call `context` here, it's just an array of variables) would be used to store all variables used in the graph. In `CODE A`, only `title` is used:

- a `GET` node will just return the value `total` from `context`
- a `SET` node will assign the value given, inside the array `context`

---

### Another example

Before I try to implement it in JS I wanted to check with another example:

```
var total, other;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  total -= other * random();
  other = (other + 2) / 3
  print(other)

}

print(total)
```

Here's the graph for the above code:
[image]

Comment: could you add back the links to the UE docs you were looking at? I'm starting to see your problem but I'm not entirely sure I would go the way you posted (again, I'm no expert, so I don't want to give you wrong suggestions; I need to check implementations which already exist and work, before). Personally, I would have `add` and `print` upstream the `loop`, but I see how `execution links` might serve your scope (still, I would have those on the left, as inputs). In any case, I'm not sure how you would update the `input total` for the `add` node after each iteration, without a cyclic graph

Comment: Here are the docs: [execution pins](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprint_Fundamentals#Execution_pin.2Fline) and [flow control](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprint_Fundamentals#flow_control_explained)

Comment: @mapofemergence, I agree with you on "I'm not sure how you would update the input total for the add node after each iteration" I thought about this morning: that doesn't work. Instead, it's the assign total node that needs to be linked by a control link, not the add node. Here's [one screenshot](https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/attachments/6102-capture.png). In the doc, they say: "for example, the multiplication node, doesn't have execution pins. Those nodes are only executed when their outputs are eventually connected to a node that does have execution pins."

Comment: mmm, I'm afraid this is getting much more complicated than I thought originally. I see in your screenshot two concepts I've never used, nor considered before: 1. that `SET` node seems to be setting the value of an upstream node (meaning you DO have a cyclic graph, it is just not shown explicitly) 2. UE has two different type of `lines` or `links` which are resolved differently (forward vs backward). This introduces new complexity to the logic you need in your interpreter, which is required only if you need to generate code which will run an application or engine. Is it what you're aiming to?

Comment: @mapofemergence, Here's [`CODE A` fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiXj1.png). It is indeed a little more complicated but I really think it can be done easily. **1.** to me the `SET` node is just a function that will assign the value given to the variable: I'm thinking of having a `context` object that stores all variables used by the graph. In our case, there would only be `title`. Therefore whenever there's a `SET` node it will assign the value to the variable in `context`. **2.** That's exactly it: two types of links => two types of "interpretation".

Comment: @mapofemergence, Like you said it would then be much easier to generate code from the graph allowing the implementation of some kind of a compiler instead of having an interpreter. I'll edit my answer several modifications

Comment: @mapofemergence, here's an update on the project, the first working version of the "transcripter": [first demo](https://image.ibb.co/j6SHE5/newDEMO.gif), [second demo](https://image.ibb.co/cd98Mk/newDEMO2.gif). It works a bit like I explained in my last post but it uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to find the arguments needed by a node.

Comment: that looks neat, @Ivan, I see where you're going. As a side note: I assume that the target of your evaluation is now hard-coded, right? What about having your `Interpret Graph` button itself live inside a node, so you can connect your graph to the `resolver` node directly? BTW, I suspect this question has become more like a forum thread, which I'm not sure is inline with SO's guidelines... :/ Should you move the conversation somewhere else, let me know. I'll keep an eye on your repo too